# I have a 3x3 grid. How can I make my elements fit in my first column according to the width of the longest using flexbox?

Tags: css

I am trying to have an effect similar to the one in the image. The first column occupies the width of the longest element. the same would happen with the third column. and finally the middle column would occupy the remaining space. How can I do it and what am I doing wrong?

this is my code live:

http://jsfiddle.net/sr60wvLy/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="h-100">
      <div class="d-flex margin">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center indicators" style="border:1px solid red;">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <i class="fa fa-charging-station fa-lg margin"> icon</i>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-center">
            <span > ELECTRICITY</span>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="w-100 flex-center flex-grow-1 margin">
          <div class="d-flex w-100">
            <div class="planning" style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#73c0dd">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#e6c22e">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#246DC9">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#8787CD">&nbsp;</div>

          </div> 

        </div>
        <div class="d-flex margin" style="border:1px solid red;" >
          <div class="d-flex flex-center">
            <span class="flex-center totals"> 50</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex" >
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center margin" style="border:1px solid red;">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <i class="fa fa-charging-station fa-lg margin"> icon</i>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-center">
            <span > ENERGY AND PETROLEUM</span>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="w-100 flex-center flex-grow-1 margin" >
          <div class="d-flex w-100">
            <div class="planning" style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#73c0dd">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#e6c22e">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#246DC9">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height: 30px; width:25%; background:#8787CD">&nbsp;</div>

          </div> 

        </div>
        <div class="d-flex margin" style="border:1px solid red;" >
          <div class="d-flex flex-center">
            <span class="flex-center"> 50</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: if you use boostrap, use bootsrap built-in class, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/ take your time to read the doc to understand how to use it.